# An unexpected exception occurred while binding a dynamic operation - using Activator for dynamic variable and generic class

Tags: c#

I Cannot an answer for this issue in the forum even though there is already similar title.
I have a code getting list of types and instantiate them within the dynamic variable as follow -

```
...
 Type[] typelist = GetTypesInNamespace(myAssembly, "somenamespace");
             for (int i = 0; i < typelist.Length; i++)
             {    
                if (somelogic == true)
                {
                     Classes.Add(typelist[i]); 
                }
             }
 Type tt =  Classes[somelogictofineindex];
 dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(tt);//implement class constractor
 obj.someobject = new someobject()//error raised
...
```

this will work properly

```
 dynamic obj = SameClassAppearinActivator();
 obj.someobject = new someobject()//works OK
```

i compared the objects(Activator and specific) and they are similar.
Any idea how to detect what is wrong with the dynamic Activator?

Comment: Screening the issue i found that its not possible to make conversion from one object to another, why for specific object there is no problem but with reflection there is a problem to convert?